# Save a Plot object in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

Does anyone know how to save a `plot` object (made by `self.plot = Plot(self)`) and then plotted using `self.plot.plot()` with various functions. I tried saving the plot using `self.plot.savefig()` but got the error that a Plot object has no attribute `savefig`.

Any other suggestions for how to save this plot? I'd love to save it as a figure since my end goal is to combine several of the plots into one pdf. I'm using python and specifically `tkinter`. Thank you!

Comment: Could you please provide us with a minimal example of what you are doing? … and please do not use a comment but rather [edit] your question, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The Figure needs a FigureCanvas to draw on. In other words, don't call `savefig` until after the FigureCanvas has been established:

Try this it may work

```
# a tk.DrawingArea
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, master=root)
canvas.show()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=Tk.TOP, fill=Tk.BOTH, expand=1)
f.savefig('output.png')
```